# How to extract contour and put landmark on it?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a binary mask, I want to have the landmarks on the object boundary (contour) and then extract the patches from those landmarks. Could you please guide how to do it? or if there is any code to get help, please share.

[image]

I want to get contour, like this:

[image]

and then automatically put some landmarks on it and extract patches.

What I did was like the following extract the harris corners:

```
from skimage import feature 
tmp = feature.corner_harris(data,method='eps',k=0.05,eps=1e-6,sigma=1.0)
plt.imshow(tmp)
plt.show()

feat_harris=[]
# Minimum distance in Harris Corner Detector Non-maximum Suppression
mindis = 5
feat_harris.append(feature.peak_local_max(tmp,min_distance=mindis))
print feat_harris,len(feat_harris[0])
```

input and output of harris:

[image]
[image]
The output is 35 points coordinates for example. Is this an efficient way to extract points on object boundary?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are trying to detect the edges of an object?

Comment: Since you have a binary image why not just  just use the opencv findcontours see- http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html

Comment: @AmalVincent thanks for sharing the link, however, I need some points which are the patch center and then I will be able to extract patches around object boundary. How is this possible?